# Stuck with XNA code: Shooter. No idea what I have done wrong

Tags: c#, xna

I'm trying to implement the Scene manager and entity manager into my project as well as figure out how the splash screen works, for some reason unknown to me I cannot fix it. also my game class has gone haywire and I dont know why :(

Can anyone help?

```
enterusing System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.Touch;

using ChopperAttack2.Scene;
using ChopperAttack2.Render;

namespace ChopperAttack2
{
/// <summary>
/// This is the main type for my game
/// </summary>
public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
{
    private GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
    public GraphicsDeviceManager Graphics
    {
        get { return this.graphics; }
        set { this.graphics = value; }
    }
    private Dictionary<String, BaseManager> managers;
    public Dictionary<String, BaseManager> Managers
    {
        get { return this.managers; }            
    }

    public Game1()
    {
        this.graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
        this.Content.RootDirectory = "Content";      

        this.managers = new Dictionary<string, BaseManager>();    
    }

    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        SceneManager sceneManager = new SceneManager(this);
        RenderManager renderManager = new RenderManager(this);

        base.Initialize();
    }

    public void AddManager(BaseManager manager)
    {
        BaseManager checkManager = null;
        if (managers.TryGetValue(manager.Name, out checkManager))
        {
            throw new Exception("Manager type " + manager.Name + " already exists within the game engine");
        }

        managers.Add(manager.Name, manager);
    }

    public BaseManager GetManager(String managerName)
    {
        BaseManager manager = null;
        if (!managers.TryGetValue(managerName, out manager))
        {
            // Manager wasn't found
        }

        return manager;
    }

    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        foreach (KeyValuePair<String, BaseManager> pair in managers)
        {
            (pair.Value).LoadContent();
        }
    }

    protected override void UnloadContent()
    {
        foreach (KeyValuePair<String, BaseManager> pair in managers)
        {
            (pair.Value).UnloadContent();
        }
    }

    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        foreach (KeyValuePair<String, BaseManager> pair in managers)
        {
            (pair.Value).Update(gameTime);
        }
    }

    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        foreach (KeyValuePair<String, BaseManager> pair in managers)
        {
            (pair.Value).Draw(gameTime);
        }

    }
}
```

}

```
    SpriteBatch spriteBatch;

    // Represents the player 
    Player player;

    // Keyboard states used to determine key presses
    KeyboardState currentKeyboardState;
    KeyboardState previousKeyboardState;

    // Gamepad states used to determine button presses
    GamePadState currentGamePadState;
    GamePadState previousGamePadState;

    // A movement speed for the player
    float playerMoveSpeed;

    // Image used to display the static background
    Texture2D mainBackground;

    // Parallaxing Layers
    ParallaxingBackground bgLayer1;
    ParallaxingBackground bgLayer2;

    // Enemies
    Texture2D enemyTexture;
    List<Enemy> enemies;

    // The rate at which the enemies appear
    TimeSpan enemySpawnTime;
    TimeSpan previousSpawnTime;

    // A random number generator
    Random random;

    Texture2D projectileTexture;
    List<Projectile> projectiles;

    // The rate of fire of the player laser
    TimeSpan fireTime;
    TimeSpan previousFireTime;

    // Explosion graphics list
    Texture2D explosionTexture;
    List<Animation> explosions;

    // The sound that is played when a laser is fired
    SoundEffect laserSound;


    // The sound used when the player or an enemy dies
    SoundEffect explosionSound;


    // The music played during gameplay
    Song gameplayMusic;

    //Number that holds the player score
    int score;
    // The font used to display UI elements
    SpriteFont font;

    /// <summary>
    /// Allows the game to perform any initialization it needs to before starting to run.
    /// This is where it can query for any required services and load any non-graphic
    /// related content.  Calling base.Initialize will enumerate through any components
    /// and initialize them as well.
    /// </summary>
    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        //Initialize the player class
        player = new Player();

        // Set a constant player move speed
        playerMoveSpeed = 8.0f;

        //Enable the FreeDrag gesture.
        TouchPanel.EnabledGestures = GestureType.FreeDrag;

        bgLayer1 = new ParallaxingBackground();
        bgLayer2 = new ParallaxingBackground();

        // Initialize the enemies list
        enemies = new List<Enemy>();

        // Set the time keepers to zero
        previousSpawnTime = TimeSpan.Zero;

        // Used to determine how fast enemy respawns
        enemySpawnTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0f); 

        // Initialize our random number generator
        random = new Random();

        projectiles = new List<Projectile>();

        // Set the laser to fire every quarter second
        fireTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(.15f);

        // Initialize the explosion list
        explosions = new List<Animation>();

        //Set player's score to zero
        score = 0;

        base.Initialize();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// LoadContent will be called once per game and is the place to load
    /// all of your content.
    /// </summary>
    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        // Create a new SpriteBatch, which can be used to draw textures.
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);

        // Load the player resources
        Animation playerAnimation = new Animation();
        Texture2D playerTexture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("shipAnimation");
        playerAnimation.Initialize(playerTexture, Vector2.Zero, 115, 69, 8, 30, Color.White, 1f, true);


        Vector2 playerPosition = new Vector2(GraphicsDevice.Viewport.TitleSafeArea.X, GraphicsDevice.Viewport.TitleSafeArea.Y
        + GraphicsDevice.Viewport.TitleSafeArea.Height / 2);
        player.Initialize(playerAnimation, playerPosition);

        // Load the parallaxing background
        bgLayer1.Initialize(Content, "bgLayer1", GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width, -1);
        bgLayer2.Initialize(Content, "bgLayer2", GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width, -2);

        mainBackground = Content.Load<Texture2D>("mainbackground");

        enemyTexture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("mineAnimation");

        projectileTexture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("laser");

        explosionTexture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("explosion");

        // Load the music
        gameplayMusic = Content.Load<Song>("sound/gameMusic");


        // Load the laser and explosion sound effect
        laserSound = Content.Load<SoundEffect>("sound/laserFire");
        explosionSound = Content.Load<SoundEffect>("sound/explosion");

        // Load the score font
        font = Content.Load<SpriteFont>("gameFont");


        // Start the music right away
        PlayMusic(gameplayMusic);

    }

    private void PlayMusic(Song song)
    {
        // Due to the way the MediaPlayer plays music,
        // we have to catch the exception. Music will play when the game is not tethered
        try
        {
            // Play the music
            MediaPlayer.Play(song);


            // Loop the currently playing song
            MediaPlayer.IsRepeating = true;
        }
        catch { }
    }

    private void AddExplosion(Vector2 position)
    {
        Animation explosion = new Animation();
        explosion.Initialize(explosionTexture, position, 134, 134, 12, 45, Color.White, 1f, false);
        explosions.Add(explosion);
    }

    private void AddEnemy()
    {
        // Create the animation object
        Animation enemyAnimation = new Animation();

        // Initialize the animation with the correct animation information
        enemyAnimation.Initialize(enemyTexture, Vector2.Zero, 47, 61, 8, 30, Color.White, 1f, true);

        // Randomly generate the position of the enemy
        Vector2 position = new Vector2(GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width + enemyTexture.Width / 2, random.Next(100, GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height - 100));

        // Create an enemy
        Enemy enemy = new Enemy();

        // Initialize the enemy
        enemy.Initialize(enemyAnimation, position);

        // Add the enemy to the active enemies list
        enemies.Add(enemy);
    }

    private void UpdateEnemies(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        // Spawn a new enemy enemy every 1.5 seconds
        if (gameTime.TotalGameTime - previousSpawnTime > enemySpawnTime)
        {
            previousSpawnTime = gameTime.TotalGameTime;

            // Add an Enemy
            AddEnemy();
        }

        // Update the Enemies
        for (int i = enemies.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            enemies[i].Update(gameTime);

            if (enemies[i].Active == false)
            {
                // If not active and health <= 0
                if (enemies[i].Health <= 0)
                {
                    // Add an explosion
                    AddExplosion(enemies[i].Position);

                    // Play the explosion sound
                    explosionSound.Play();

                    //Add to the player's score
                    score += enemies[i].Value;
                }

                enemies.RemoveAt(i);
            }
        }
    }

    private void UpdateExplosions(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        for (int i = explosions.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            explosions[i].Update(gameTime);
            if (explosions[i].Active == false)
            {
                explosions.RemoveAt(i);
            }
        }
    }

    private void AddProjectile(Vector2 position)
    {
        Projectile projectile = new Projectile();
        projectile.Initialize(GraphicsDevice.Viewport, projectileTexture, position);
        projectiles.Add(projectile);
    }

    private void UpdateProjectiles()
    {
        // Update the Projectiles
        for (int i = projectiles.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            projectiles[i].Update();

            if (projectiles[i].Active == false)
            {
                projectiles.RemoveAt(i);
            }
        }
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// UnloadContent will be called once per game and is the place to unload
    /// all content.
    /// </summary>
    protected override void UnloadContent()
    {
        // TODO: Unload any non ContentManager content here
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Allows the game to run logic such as updating the world,
    /// checking for collisions, gathering input, and playing audio.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        // Allows the game to exit
        if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)
            this.Exit();

        // Save the previous state of the keyboard and game pad so we can determinesingle key/button presses
        previousGamePadState = currentGamePadState;
        previousKeyboardState = currentKeyboardState;

        // Read the current state of the keyboard and gamepad and store it
        currentKeyboardState = Keyboard.GetState();
        currentGamePadState = GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One);

        //Update the player
        UpdatePlayer(gameTime);

        // Update the parallaxing background
        bgLayer1.Update();
        bgLayer2.Update();

        // Update the enemies
        UpdateEnemies(gameTime);

        // Update the collision
        UpdateCollision();

        // Update the projectiles
        UpdateProjectiles();

        // Update the explosions
        UpdateExplosions(gameTime);


        base.Update(gameTime);
    }

    private void UpdatePlayer(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        player.Update(gameTime);

        // Windows Phone Controls
        while (TouchPanel.IsGestureAvailable)
        {
            GestureSample gesture = TouchPanel.ReadGesture();
            if (gesture.GestureType == GestureType.FreeDrag)
            {
                player.Position += gesture.Delta;
            }
        }

        // Get Thumbstick Controls
        player.Position.X += currentGamePadState.ThumbSticks.Left.X * playerMoveSpeed;
        player.Position.Y -= currentGamePadState.ThumbSticks.Left.Y * playerMoveSpeed;

        // Use the Keyboard / Dpad
        if (currentKeyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Left) ||
        currentGamePadState.DPad.Left == ButtonState.Pressed)
        {
            player.Position.X -= playerMoveSpeed;
        }
        if (currentKeyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Right) ||
        currentGamePadState.DPad.Right == ButtonState.Pressed)
        {
            player.Position.X += playerMoveSpeed;
        }
        if (currentKeyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Up) ||
        currentGamePadState.DPad.Up == ButtonState.Pressed)
        {
            player.Position.Y -= playerMoveSpeed;
        }
        if (currentKeyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Down) ||
        currentGamePadState.DPad.Down == ButtonState.Pressed)
        {
            player.Position.Y += playerMoveSpeed;
        }


        // Make sure that the player does not go out of bounds
        player.Position.X = MathHelper.Clamp(player.Position.X, 0, GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width - player.Width);
        player.Position.Y = MathHelper.Clamp(player.Position.Y, 0, GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height - player.Height);

        // Fire only every interval we set as the fireTime
        if (gameTime.TotalGameTime - previousFireTime > fireTime)
        {
            // Reset our current time
            previousFireTime = gameTime.TotalGameTime;

            // Add the projectile, but add it to the front and center of the player
            AddProjectile(player.Position + new Vector2(player.Width / 2, 0));

            // Play the laser sound
            laserSound.Play();
        }

        // reset score if player health goes to zero
        if (player.Health <= 0)
        {
            player.Health = 100;
            score = 0;
        }

    }

    private void UpdateCollision()
    {
        // Use the Rectangle's built-in intersect functionto 
        // determine if two objects are overlapping
        Rectangle rectangle1;
        Rectangle rectangle2;

        // Only create the rectangle once for the player
        rectangle1 = new Rectangle((int)player.Position.X,
        (int)player.Position.Y,
        player.Width,
        player.Height);

        // Do the collision between the player and the enemies
        for (int i = 0; i < enemies.Count; i++)
        {
            rectangle2 = new Rectangle((int)enemies[i].Position.X,
            (int)enemies[i].Position.Y,
            enemies[i].Width,
            enemies[i].Height);

            // Determine if the two objects collided with each
            // other
            if (rectangle1.Intersects(rectangle2))
            {
                // Subtract the health from the player based on
                // the enemy damage
                player.Health -= enemies[i].Damage;

                // Since the enemy collided with the player
                // destroy it
                enemies[i].Health = 0;

                // If the player health is less than zero we died
                if (player.Health <= 0)
                    player.Active = false;
            }

        }

        // Projectile vs Enemy Collision
        for (int i = 0; i < projectiles.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < enemies.Count; j++)
            {
                // Create the rectangles we need to determine if we collided with each other
                rectangle1 = new Rectangle((int)projectiles[i].Position.X -
                projectiles[i].Width / 2, (int)projectiles[i].Position.Y -
                projectiles[i].Height / 2, projectiles[i].Width, projectiles[i].Height);

                rectangle2 = new Rectangle((int)enemies[j].Position.X - enemies[j].Width / 2,
                (int)enemies[j].Position.Y - enemies[j].Height / 2,
                enemies[j].Width, enemies[j].Height);

                // Determine if the two objects collided with each other
                if (rectangle1.Intersects(rectangle2))
                {
                    enemies[j].Health -= projectiles[i].Damage;
                    projectiles[i].Active = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// This is called when the game should draw itself.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

        // Start drawing
        spriteBatch.Begin();

        spriteBatch.Draw(mainBackground, Vector2.Zero, Color.White);

        // Draw the moving background
        bgLayer1.Draw(spriteBatch);
        bgLayer2.Draw(spriteBatch);

        // Draw the Player
        player.Draw(spriteBatch);

        // Draw the Enemies
        for (int i = 0; i < enemies.Count; i++)
        {
            enemies[i].Draw(spriteBatch);
        }

        // Draw the Projectiles
        for (int i = 0; i < projectiles.Count; i++)
        {
            projectiles[i].Draw(spriteBatch);
        }

        // Draw the explosions
        for (int i = 0; i < explosions.Count; i++)
        {
            explosions[i].Draw(spriteBatch);
        }

        // Draw the score
        spriteBatch.DrawString(font, "score: " + score, new Vector2(GraphicsDevice.Viewport.TitleSafeArea.X, GraphicsDevice.Viewport.TitleSafeArea.Y), Color.White);
        // Draw the player health
        spriteBatch.DrawString(font, "health: " + player.Health, new Vector2(GraphicsDevice.Viewport.TitleSafeArea.X, GraphicsDevice.Viewport.TitleSafeArea.Y + 30), Color.White);

        //Stop drawing
        spriteBatch.End();

        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
}
```

}

I Think the main problem is here:

```
    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        foreach (KeyValuePair<String, BaseManager> pair in managers)
        {
            (pair.Value).Draw(gameTime);
        }

    }
}
```

}

```
    SpriteBatch spriteBatch;

    // Represents the player 
    Player player;

    // Keyboard states used to determine key presses
    KeyboardState currentKeyboardState;
    KeyboardState previousKeyboardState;
```

Error message is Spritebatch - A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods?

Comment: Please describe errors you have, or a specific problem.

Comment: Well...so what is your *actual* problem? Provide us with an Error/Exception/CompilerError (it's Name, Message, Location).

Comment: 11 errors: Expected class delegate enum interface or struct,

Comment: What don't you understand in the message "A namespace cannot directly contain members"? You need to add them to a class. There are no such things as global variables in C#. Furthermore, you should not just dump your code here and hope that someone will find the mistake.

Comment: Sorry Nico, I just don't know what I'm doing, I thought someone may be able to help

Comment: Why is 'enter' in line 1? Is this a typo?

Answer (score 0):

(Making an answer rather than a comment so I can format code)

Your problem is that you need to brush up on your c# skills before you try to cut and paste XNA code from a book or other tutorial. As others have said code must be inside a class/struct block otherwise you get the errors you are seeing.

C# code should look like this:

```
// Code cannot be here
namespace SomeNameSpace
{
    //..or here

    class SomeClass
    {
        //Now you can put code here
    }
}
```

If your code is structured that way then look for missing { } sets that are causing the code to be outside the class block. Its easy to do that with cut and paste.